# how to restore attachments in mac outlook?

Tags: ms-office

I had an email sent to me back in february of this year with an attachment. Now when I view that email, instead of seeing the attachment, i see this:

[image: inline attachment message]

How do I recover this attachment?

Comment: Can you add some details, as in the OS version.

Comment: Did you send that attachment then got it send back to you ?

Comment: nope. original attachment was sent to me. I'm running OS X 10.9.3 and Outlook 2011.

Comment: also, others who received this email are unable to open the attachment. Additionally the sender (from windows machine if that matters) is unable to retrieve it either.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is one specific email, your best choice is to open the web version of your email, and get it from there.

It probably got lost in the email transfer protocols.

Comment: I tried opening in webmail but no luck. :-(